# Wal position to wal archive number

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, write-ahead-logging, standby

I want to manage the copy of archiving to remote location.
For that I want to delete all the archives I copied unless they are required by the standby.

So, for running `pg_archivecleanup $ARCLOC $CHECKPOINT` I need to find the most recent checkpoint which is ok to delete. I don't look on the recent `.backup` files as it is too old for my archive capacity. What I do want to look on is the `replay_location` \ `replay_lsn`(depend on the version) from `pg_stat_replication`.

However, I do not know how to convert from `replay_location` value to checkpoint value. I.e. from something like `7/2DBCED18` to `000000020000000700000029`.

**Answer:**

Function is: `pg_xlogfile_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a backup or stop a backup you'll get a WAL location, if you want to know it's physical location on disk use the following function: `select pg_xlogfile_name('7/2DBCED18');`

Comment: Please explain a bit  more how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg_controldata to get the latest checkpoint's redo wal file.
and pg_archivecleanup to remove wals before that point.

```
pg_controldata -D $PGDATA

g_control version number:            1002
Catalog version number:               201707211
Database system identifier:           6672741145817362070
Database cluster state:               in archive recovery
pg_control last modified:             Mon 26 Sep 2022 09:53:49 AM CEST
Latest checkpoint location:           35D3/CEE95008
Prior checkpoint location:            35D3/CEE95008
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    35D2/A93FBD20
Latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file:    000000AE000035D2000000A9

pg_archivecleanup pg_wal/ 000000AE000035D2000000A9
```